# Placeholder text when asking a question still implies this site is only about UI design

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

When asking a question, the placeholder on the Title field and the "how to ask" text to the right both suggest this site is only about "usability and human computer interaction". This may be a holdover from before we merged with UXExchange to form UX Stack Exchange. Either way, it's no longer accurate.

Can we change it?

[image]

Comment: I never thought it was unusual, but I guess HCI as a term can be intimidating and not explicitly evocative of UX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for catching this.  I've updated it to read "user experience" instead of "usability and human computer interaction".